# CRUD operation using hibernate + jersey ws

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate, model, jersey

I have generated a model and dao with hibernate tools.

Now I would like to use the model and dao to make a query on a database using a restful web service with jersey.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
Check this question: [REST with Java (JAX-RS) using Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190934/rest-with-java-jax-rs-using-jersey).

Generally, there are a lot of solutions, you have to search some.
I think that most efficient for start is this one:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

In that example you have a lot of information for creating everything including CRUD with Jersey in general.

After that you can check this:

http://persistentdesigns.com/wp/jersey-spring-and-jpa/

There is explained process of integrating Jersey and JPA in spring.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I had just visit vogella's  tutorials, I would like to know if there is a way to map, using hibernete model and dao resources, for use in jersey web service.

Comment: As I said, general info is in vogella tutorial about CRUD. Working example of jersey, spring and jpa is given with third link.

Comment: I use Hibernate tools for generating model and dao. You say that if I use Hibernate Jpa for use this object e make use of jersey I can do the job. Right? Hibernate jpa jar is different to other kind of hibernate jar? Also , can I use Jpa without spring?